# How can I send requests to cloudflare WARP+ from users who connect to the Ubuntu server with Softether?

Tags: networking, ubuntu, vpn, cloudflare, softether

I have an Ubuntu server and I use it as a softether vpn server. I recently installed cloudflare WARP+ on it. After connecting to the server with softether vpn client, the user's requests will go to cloudflare WARP+ and be answered. But when cloudflare WARP+ It turns on, I can no longer connect to my server.

Please guide me, how can I fix this problem.

Server IP: 5.75.202.101

cloudflare WARP+ IP: 172.16.0.2

Comment: WARP is basically another vpn tunnel, so you'll have to be careful of what traffic is getting included/excluded. In Zero Trust > Settings > WARP client > device settings > profile > configure > check your Split Tunnels settings and related routing configs. You didn't include any of the configurations you've done, so it's hard to guess what the problem is

Comment: @Cpt.Whale I don't have enough knowledge about Linux. That's why I couldn't do anything. So I came here and asked a question.

Comment: We don't have enough knowledge about your configurations like vpn routes or WARP client configs. I would recommend just using either warp *or* your vpn server, but not both. Using both will be very difficult unless you understand how routing works and can troubleshoot it in linux,

Comment: @Cpt.Whale Thank you for taking the time to reply me. Let's say I have a new ubuntu server without any changes. Now what I want is to install warp+ cloudflare on this server and in whatever way you say, to the server Connect and get answers to my requests from Warp+ Cloudflare.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your local client to connect to your remote ubuntu server using WARP, then you should follow the steps here to use SSH for example: [Connect with SSH through Cloudflare Tunnel](https://developers.cloudflare.com/cloudflare-one/connections/connect-networks/use-cases/ssh/) instead of using a second vpn service like Softether. To clarify:

- Cloudflare WARP connects clients to Cloudflare like a vpn
- Cloudflare Tunnel connects WARP clients to each other like a private network

The linked instructions are for doing that with a linux instance hosted in GCP, but the steps are the same for wherever your ubuntu server is located.

Comment: Greetings.
This did not help me.
I have an Ubuntu server in my home network, and I installed Warp + Cloudflare on it, and after connecting it, I ssh to the server without any problems, because we were all in the same network and gateway. But on the server that is outside It is from my network, I do the same things, and after connecting it to Warp + Cloudflare, my access is cut off.